# adb bugreport get nothing

Tags: android, logging, adb

When I wanna get battery log from my Android Phone(Android T insided) which is already run one night, only a little log I could get. I don't know what happend? Log shows that my log is reseted when I conneceted my phone on morning.

Befor test, I use `adb shell dumpsys batterystats --reset` and `adb shell dumpsys batterystats --enable full-wake-history`.

After one night test, I only use command `adb bugreport` to export my log, but log contains only 1 or 2 minutes log, not all night.

Comment: How large was the log of 1-2 minutes? adb log uses a cyclic buffer of a specified size, so older messages are overwritten. You can change the log buffer size in developer settings.

Comment: It was happened randomly, I don't do something about buffer settings.When I do nothing about the phone, log don't disappear, but I do some test case and put it all tonight until it close automatically, log disappea.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be caused by Battery Optimization feature, if your phone has one Try disabling it as it sometimes interferes with the logging process.

Comment: Iike battery self-adaption？（Eg. Samsung）I will try it.Thx.